Students are murdering their teachers
There's a movie I saw part of on TV back in the late 90s, these are the details I can remember:

It has to be old enough to be on British TV around 1997, but it wasn't too old as it was in colour and there wasn't noticeable film grain.
It was in English, but I don't recall if it was American or British, I'd guess probably British as:
The students had uniforms which included a dark blazer
There was a scene in which they lock a teacher in a chemistry lab and gas him to death
It's not if... (1968)

Any ideas?

Not a lot to go on here. Maybe describe the uniforms a bit more. What era did the movie itself look like? Any other notable scenes? Can you describe any actors?

Could it be The Faculty from 1998? I don't remember too much about the story, but the students were trying to kill their alien teachers.

@MeatTrademark No sorry it's got to be older than that.

Kind of a stretch, but in Class of 1999 (1990), most students wear black leather coats and a teacher (who's an evil robot) is blown up in a chemistry lab.

A possibility is Unman, Wittering and Zigo (British,1971).
Some students admit to a new teacher that they murdered his predecessor. I don't recall anything about a chemistry lab and gassing however.
The usual links...
Wikipedia
imdb

Unfortunately this isn't the one, though it was an excellent film, thank you very much for the answer.
